# Error creating "writeFieldReport" results in Abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I am new to the forum. I am not an expert programmer but I am facing the need to scripting in python in order to run Finite Element simulation with Abaqus without a GUI. The simulation runs fine but when I try to generate a text file containing the results I got the following error prompt

*File "C:/...my_scrypt.py, line 208, in  INTEGRATION_POINT),))
There are no active entities. No report has been generated*

Here is the script:

```
(197)    from odbAccess import *
(198)    from abaqusConstants import *
(199)    from odbMaterial import *
(200)    from odbSection import *
(201)    
(202)    o1 = session.openOdb(name='C:/Temp/Job-1.odb')
(203)    odb = session.odbs['C:/Temp/Job-1.odb'].steps['apply_load']
(204)    session.writeFieldReport(fileName='C:/Temp/abaqus.rpt', append=ON, 
(205)        sortItem='Element Label', odb=odb, step=0, frame=1, 
(206)        outputPosition=INTEGRATION_POINT, variable=(('PEMAG', 
(207)        INTEGRATION_POINT), ('PRESSONLY', INTEGRATION_POINT), ('S', 
(208)        INTEGRATION_POINT), ))
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You must display some elements in the viewport first.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: Abaqus needs to somehow now from which elements you're trying to read the results. If you're running the script from Abaqus Viewer, then first post the elements you want to get the data for in the viewport. If you're running it from the command line, define a display group and set the appropriate parameter for writeFieldReport.

Comment: besides the missing displaygroup, you have the symbol `odb` pointing to a step, which makes it a step object not an odb object.

Comment: Are you running this script from within Abaqus Viewer? Or are you hoping to export data without the GUI?

Comment: I am hoping to export the data in a text file from the command window. I am launching the script with this command
os.system("start abaqus cae nogui=C:/Temp/test")

Comment: as agentp said, fix line 203. odb = session.odbs['C:/Temp/Job-1.odb']. then tell us if you still have a problem.

Comment: odb = session.odbs['C:/Temp/Job-1.odb'] fixed but it still doesn't work.
but I have added these lines:
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=o1)
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.setFrame(step=0, frame=1)
before line 203 and everithing works fine :/

Comment: no idea why is working. but thanks a lot for the help

Comment: You should post your working code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the help guys. Here is the working code:

```
from odbAccess import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from odbMaterial import *
from odbSection import *

o1 = session.openOdb(name='C:/Temp/Job-1.odb')
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=o1)
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.setFrame(step=0, frame=1)
odb = session.odbs['C:/Temp/Job-1.odb']
session.fieldReportOptions.setValues(columnLayout=SEPARATE_TABLES)
session.writeFieldReport(fileName='C:/Temp/abaqus.rpt', append=OFF, 
    sortItem='Element Label', odb=odb, step=0, frame=1, 
    outputPosition=INTEGRATION_POINT, variable=(('PEMAG', 
    INTEGRATION_POINT), ('PRESSONLY', INTEGRATION_POINT), ('S', 
    INTEGRATION_POINT), ))
```

Answer (score 1):

When I started programming with Python this was one of my first lines of code as well, which worked fine. However, now that I am expanding my code and such I started to get the same error as you described: "There are no active entities. No report has been generated".

In your case, you are using an existing viewport, called 'Viewport: 1', however, when creating a new viewport you have to make that viewport current.
This is the following code that I use to create myViewport:

```
myViewport = session.Viewport(name=ViewportName, origin=(0, -100),width=250, height=150)
myViewport.odbDisplay.commonOptions.setValues(visibleEdges=FREE,deformationScaling=UNIFORM,uniformScaleFactor=(1))

# Open the output database and associate it with the viewport.
# Then set the plot state to CONTOURS_ON_DEF

try: myOdb = visualization.openOdb(path=odbNames)
except (AbaqusException), value:  print ('Error:', value)

myViewport.setValues(displayedObject=myOdb)
myViewport.odbDisplay.display.setValues(plotState=(CONTOURS_ON_DEF,))

myViewport.viewportAnnotationOptions.setValues(triad=OFF,title=OFF,state=OFF,compass=OFF, legendDecimalPlaces=2,legendNumberFormat=FIXED)
myViewport.odbDisplay.basicOptions.setValues(coordSystemDisplay=OFF, renderBeamProfiles=ON)

myViewport.view.rotate(xAngle=90,yAngle=90,zAngle=0)
myViewport.view.rotate(xAngle=90,yAngle=90,zAngle=0)
myViewport.view.rotate(xAngle=0, yAngle=0, zAngle=180)
#        myViewport.view.rotate(mode=TOTAL)
myViewport.view.pan(xFraction=0.1) # yFraction for vertical panning
myViewport.view.setValues(projection=PARALLEL)
myViewport.makeCurrent() #This makes the viewport current
```